# delete form-control in form-row symfony/twig

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

When i create this builder

```
    $builder
        ->add('categorie', EntityType::class, [
        // This field shows all the categories
        'class'    => Categorie::class,
        'mapped' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'attr' => ['class' => 'mdb-select']
        ])
```

and when i do **form_row(form.name)**

i see class has value **'form-control'** automaticaly, but me i'm use MDBootstrap and i want to set only **mdb-select**

Comment: what does your twig template look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by one of the [default form themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#symfony-built-in-form-themes) of Symfony, I think by default currently it's the [bootstrap 4 theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html).

To get rid of that class across the whole app you can [change the default form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-all-forms), e.g. to form div layout:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    form_themes: ['form_div_layout.html.twig']
    # ...
```

The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) also describes how to remove the class in smaller scope.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change default theme layout of form or you can create your own custom layout.