# How to prevent Twig from adding form-control class to the fields it generates?

Tags: php, symfony, bootstrap-4, twig, symfony-forms

I have this code:

```
{% for key, customField in customFields %}
   {{ form_widget(formVirtualTerminal['cf_' ~ key], { 'attr': {'placeholder': customField['FieldDisplayName'], 'name': customField['FieldName'], 'class' : 'row no-gutters mb-3'} }) }} 
{% endfor %}
```

which traverses an array and outputs some fields for it. However, for reasons unknown to me, a `form-control` class is generated into all these fields and that ruins the design of the page.

In this question ([delete form-control in form-row symfony/twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616813/delete-form-control-in-form-row-symfony-twig)) it's mentioned that this is part of a default Bootstrap theme and they discuss how this theme can be deactivated on application level.

However, I prefer not to do such radical changes if possible. I would like to tell Twig not to add classes.

The following is a hack which solves the problem by removing that class:

```
$("#custom-text-field-container .form-control").removeClass("form-control");
```

However, I would like to avoid writing Javascript to remove classes from fields which should never had that class in the first place.

Is there a way to tell twig not to write `form-control` class into these text fields?

Comment: In your controller, change the form builder and pass `'class' => ''` to the `attr` array in `options` of the field

Comment: @yivi thank you for your answer, I plan to do some experiments in the not-too-far future with it. At this point this is solved via a hack, which is good for the time being and I simply didn't have time to revisit the question. I have not forgotten about it, please excuse me for not giving you a feedback earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can't prevent it without making changes to the theme

You can't "tell twig not to add classes".

The `form_widget` does not accept any parameter to remove a class or attribute that will be later applied by the theme.

Basically, it has no control over what the template does, it only passes the template whatever parameters you want, and it's up to the form template how to use that information.

E.g. for HTML classes, the usual approach is simply to merge whatever classes you pass with whatever classes the template has set by default.

---

#### Workaround while keeping most of the form theme you are using

A simple recourse would be [to create to your theme based on the form theme you are using](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#reusing-parts-of-a-built-in-form-theme) (which seems to be '[bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig)')

You'd need to rewrite only the parts that hinder you, leaving everything else as it is.

E.g. a "complete" new theme could be as short as:

```
{# templates/form/your_theme.html.twig #}
{% use 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_widget_simple -%}
    {% if type is not defined or type != 'hidden' %}
        {%- set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ (type|default('') == 'file' ? ' custom-file-input' : ''))|trim}) -%}
    {% endif %}
    {%- if type is defined and (type == 'range' or type == 'color') %}
        {# Attribute "required" is not supported #}
        {%- set required = false -%}
    {% endif %}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

This is almost the same `form_widget_simple` block [as the original](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/84aa013c2c6446432b3e27b4050f9a6b0a28ac74/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L134), I simply removed the `form-control` class that is merged with the classes you can pass through.

You can use this form only in the templates you want this custom theme by doing this in the appropriate template:

```
{% form_theme form 'form/your_theme.html.twig' %}
```

Or if you want to use it by default in all forms in your application:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    form_themes: ['form/your_theme.html.twig']
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Found the file at vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig, opened it with vim and executed :%s/form-control/fckbs/g and it has changed the class which is injected, which confirms your answer. Well done and thanks.